# dynamodb putItem callback function not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    var note = {};
    note.noteid = new Date().getTime();
    note.content = event.queryStringParameters["content"];

    var res = {};

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(note),
    };

    var obj = {
        'TableName':'notes',
        'Item': {
          'note_id': {
            S: '2'
          },
          'name': {
            S: 'content'
          }
        },
        'ReturnConsumedCapacity': "TOTAL"
    };

    dynamodb.putItem(obj, function(err,result){
        console.log('function called!!');
        console.log(err);

        return response;
    });

};
```

My `putItem` is not working, the callback function is not being called. I have given full access to role of this user, but still function is not getting called.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assume you are using AWS Lambda. Since you are using the `async`/`await` pattern, the http response is eventually what `async (event) => {}` returns. In your case, that is nothing. You called `putItem` but did not wait for it. `async (event) => {}` return nothing immediately afterwards. Since the function has returned, your `putItem` call has no chances to callback.

You should convert the `putItem` call to `promise` and `await` for it. Then handle the result and return the http response.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    var note = {};
    note.noteid = new Date().getTime();
    note.content = event.queryStringParameters["content"];

    var res = {};

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(note),
    };

    var obj = {
        'TableName':'notes',
        'Item': {
          'note_id': {
            S: '2'
          },
          'name': {
            S: 'content'
          }
        },
        'ReturnConsumedCapacity': "TOTAL"
    };

    try
    {
        var result = await dynamodb.putItem(obj).promise();
        //Handle your result here!
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Felipe's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140031/how-can-i-run-synchronous-dynamodb-request-in-lambda
should help

Comment: This will return a 200 status code no matter what, which isn't probably what you want

Comment: @HarryCramer the response result can be modified in `//Handle your result here`. Of course I didn't write down how to handle the result and modify the response because it is up to the use case.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible reason for this error is because of one using  AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient() instead of AWS.DynamoDB();
In that case, DocumentClient uses the [put](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property) method instead of putItem

I kept checking the async and promise code when this was the cause